# Using Apple KeyChain Equivalent on Linux

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, gnome-keyring

I would be very much interested in using the Apple KeyChain on Linux, is this possible? (i expect no)

If not, is there a possibility to not store website passwords in firefox but the linux (mint cinnamon) keyring?

Comment: By "Apple Keyring" do you mean the iCloud Keychain online service?

Comment: yes probably, sorry, my mac is german ;-) also i wasnt aware that it is a icloud functionality

Answer (score 1):

Probably wrong forum, i found those on askUbuntu:

firefox support keyring via addins:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343026/which-is-a-safe-way-to-record-firefox-passwords-in-gnome-seahorse-keyring?noredirect=1&lq=1

chrome supports keyring:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/28019/how-to-make-chrome-chromium-remember-passwords-in-the-gnome-seahorse-keyring?noredirect=1&lq=1

Also other threads suggest to switch to "BitWarden"